# How can I make inner div to 100% width by rotating vertically if outer div is 10% width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, elementor

I have two divs (outer & inner). The **outer div's width is 10%**. When I put an **inner div with 100% width**, it contains inside the 10% width of the outer div. That's exactly how it should behave.

The problem is that I want to **rotate the inner div 90 deg** and then it should contain the **outer div's height 100%**.

[Here is the screenshot of the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fttcz.png)

[Here is what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zp1Xf.jpg)

The solution can be in **CSS** or in **Elementor**.

**Thank you** in advance.

When I rotate the inner div 90 deg, it remains the 10% width of the outer div. But it should **expand to 100% of the outer div's height**.

Comment: This is a perfect job for Grid layout, along with `text-orientation`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ralph.m Thank you! text-orientation solved my problem in Flexbox. But one problem is that, when I use text-orientation, I need to adjust the padding for the text. It moves away from the center.

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullah — I've posted a little demo below of how you might think about dealing with this layout. It needs more work, but may get you started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick example of how you might do this with Grid and a bit of Flexbox (lots of room for improvement, though):

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

article {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #e7e7e7;
  display: grid;
  gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: min-content min-content 1fr 1fr min-content;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr min-content;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.hello {
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  background: rgb(215, 149, 149);
  font-size: 3em;
  display: flex;
}

.hello p {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.dummy {
  grid-column: 4 / 5;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  background: rgb(162, 206, 226);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  font-size: 3em;
}

.ele {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 2 / 5;
  display: flex; 
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  background: #bca2f8;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.ele div {
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.going {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 5;
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  font-size: 3em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: rgb(217, 180, 111);
}

.lizard {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
}

.lizard img, .iceberg img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 50% 50%;
}

.global {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 4 / 5;
  background: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.iceberg {
  grid-column: 4 / 5;
  grid-row: 3 / 5;
}

.world {
  grid-column: 5 / 6;
  grid-row: 1 / 5;
  background: rgb(199, 104, 123);
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.globab, .going, .world, .ele {padding: 5px;}
```

```html
<article>
  <div class="hello"><p>Hello</p></div>
  <div class="dummy">Dummy</div>
  <div class="ele">
    <div>World</div>
    <div>Ele.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="going">Going</div>
  <div class="lizard">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542884738-c35f6c9c9ea2?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80" alt="lizard">
  </div>
  <div class="global">global css</div>
  <div class="iceberg">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1562089727-90aa996a6f18?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1548&q=80" alt="iceberg">
  </div>
  <div class="world">My world is not >>></div>
</article>
```